# Split window.location.search and retrieve only last word

Tags: jquery

```
var SearchString = window.location.search.substring(1);
      var KeyValuePair = SearchString.split('=');

      for(var i = 0; i < KeyValuePair.length; i++){
         //seem not to be working
          var KeyValuePair = KeyValuePair[i].split(',');
          if(KeyValuePair[0] == VarSearch){
              return KeyValuePair[1];
          }
```

The example website address is: http://google.com/?type=talks. 
window.location.search retrieves "type=talks" and then split "=" away. The words will be "type, talks". Need to match "talks" with "talks" in json: type.

Is there a easy way to retrieve the last word after split '=' away?

**Update**
The split word will be only ONE word. There is no "&" between the url address in. 
The retrieved word will be "type=talks" so need to take "talks" out from the retrieved word. "Talks" word will be compared with "talks" in json

Comment: Split on `&`, then loop that array, splitting each item on `=` and comparing `arr[1]`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: @AlexK. there is no "&"?

Comment: @AlexK. thanks! I m trying now

Comment: @AlexK - sorry I miss your example - it disappeared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var pairs = window.location.search.split("&");
var lastWord = pairs[pairs.lenght-1].split("=")[1];
```

UPDATE

If there is always only one pair then this may be simplified

```
var lastWord = window.location.search.split("=")[1];
```

But you'd better not to rely on a perfect address string, because everybody may type anything in the browser address bar

Comment: no there is no "&" so url will show only "type=talks". all links will be only one word = like "type=entertainment", etc

Comment: It will be OK, `pairs` array will contain only one element in this case.

Comment: how come it shows one word correctly when there is no "&"?